# Targeting a Collection - Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Greetings Shopify Pals!

I have a website at: https://www.blakesseedbased.com/ (password: TopSecretPass)

**The Goal:**
We will have products that vary in quantity and would like to display this quantity information between the product title and price from the featured home page products (raspberry, chocolate chip, pineapple).

**The Issue:**
Currently we're able to add content to this area, but we cannot seem to get the if else statement to work correctly. We have a collection called "Snack Bars" however our logic isn't recognising this and injecting the proper code. We tried changing the collection Snack Bars to lower and uppercease snack-bars/Snack-Bars but no luck.

**The Logic:**
IF the product item is from the Snack Bar collection, add the box quantity (box of 12).
Else, add "no quantity"

**The Code:**

```
{% if product.collections contains 'snack-bars' %}
         <span>Box of 12</span>
{% else %}
          No Box Amount
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings Birdie Golden!

The issue you're hitting is that `product.collections` is an array of Collection objects when you're accessing it in Liquid, and no collection object will ever equal a string value.

Luckily, we can easily create an array of handles using the `map` filter and assign that to a variable, like this:

```
{% assign collection_list = product.collections | map: 'handle' %}
{% if collection_list contains 'snack-bars' %}
...
```

The `map` filter above will create a new array using just the value that you pass it, so the `collection_list` variable will be an array of just-the-handles.  Since `handle` is a string, we can use `contains` as expected to see if the value we want is in the list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just want to say THANK YOU, this is totally what I was missing. I really appreciate your help, Dave!